# How can a power series with n in the denominator converge?

Tags: power-series

Example 1 from [this review of power series and the ratio test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PowerSeries.aspx) is:

$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 3} \right)}^n}}}{{n\,{7^{n + 1}}}}{{\left( {x - 5} \right)}^n}}$

It converges by the ratio test. But isn't the first term of this series undefined since it contains $n = 0$ in the denominator?

That is,

$a_0 = {\frac{{{{\left( { - 3} \right)}^0}}}{{0\,{7^{1}}}}{{\left( {x - 5} \right)}^0}} = \frac{1}{0}$

Thank you.

Comment: Carelessness on the part of the author.

Comment: Thanks. I'll send him an email. And greetings from Gwangju, @kimchilover

Comment: You get a + 1 from me for finding an error  in a published text.